# Thin-LVM readonly mode

Tags: centos7, lvm, dd

I use this command to move data of one thin lv to another lv on separate server.

dd if=/dev/vg/my-lv bs=24M | throttle -v -s 512 -w 2 -m 2000  | ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /var/my-ssh-keys/id_rsa -q root@destination-server-ip dd conv=sparse of=/dev/vg/new-lv bs=24M

After completion, I run lvdisplay thin-pool on destination server and it says :

LV write Access : read/write (activated read-only)

Though new LV creation works well in that thin pool later on.
Is it something to worry ?

Comment: Have you consider moving the files, not the disk blocks?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not have any issue. Basically, `lvdisplay` is telling that on poweron / first activation, your volume was activated read-only and then switched to read/write operation.

So if you can write to the volume, you have no issue.

Note: keep a close eye on thinpool utilization, as having no free physical space left is not going to be a good experience (read: you will lose data).